# w3c markup validation "Attribute , not allowed"

Tags: javascript, html

im getting a w3c error that i cant understand.

Error Line 430, Column 204: Attribute , not allowed on element div at this point.

This is in that row.

```
<div id="map" class="google-map" data-position-latitude="-33.428843" , data-position-longitude="-70.577836" data-marker-img="images/marker.png" data-marker-width="64" data-marker-height="58"></div>
```

Comment: You have a `,` in your tag (`data-position-latitude="-33.428843" , data-position-longitude="-70.577836"`).  Get rid of it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Don't you think that should be an answer?

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/but-it-doesnt-validate--net-16493

Comment: Did you even read the error message before posting?

Comment: @JoeFrambach I did, and i didnt understand it thats why im posting it here.. Sorry if i bother you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the ',' between latitude and longitude

```
<div id="map" class="google-map" data-position-latitude="-33.428843" data-position-longitude="-70.577836" data-marker-img="images/marker.png" data-marker-width="64" data-marker-height="58"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use commas between attributes, they will be treated like an attribute and throw the error